# How does the scope of variables in julia modules work?

Tags: for-loop, module, scope, julia

Running this code

```
module mod1
export foo

function foo()
    i=0
    for ii in 1:10
        global i+=ii
    end
    i
end

end

mod1.foo()
```

gives `UndefVarError: i not defined`.

It seems that the way to do it is by adding a `global` before the variable `i`:

```
module mod2
export bar

function bar()
    global i=0
    for ii in 1:10
        global i+=ii
    end
    i
end

end

mod2.bar()
```

This gives: `55`

Why does the first method not work? As I understand the `for` introduces a new scope. Therefore I need the global inside the loop. But why do I also need it outside of the loop?

(I am using julia 1.5.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to write this would be:

```
module mod1
export foo

function foo()
    i=0
    for ii in 1:10
        i+=ii
    end
    i
end

end
```

```
julia> mod1.foo()
55
```

There are 3 scopes introduced here (from outermost to innermost):

1. global scope of module `mod1`
2. local scope of function `foo`
3. local scope of `for` body

The [rules for scoping](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/) are explained in the manual. In this particular case: when `i` is referred to in the `for` body, we first look for a variable named `i` defined in that same scope. Since none is found, we look for it in the enclosing scope which is the [local](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#Local-Scope) scope of `foo`... and find the variable declared using `i=0`.

If no variable named `i` had been found in the local `foo` scope, we'd have had to look into the enclosing scope, which is a [*global*](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#Global-Scope) scope. And in this case, you'd have had to put the `global` keyword to explicitly allow it (because it has performance implications).

Comment: Might be good to link to the documentation: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/ and in particular https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#Local-Scope

Comment: Thank you very much for this quick and precise answer.